# Creating VBA code that calculates based off of a row of data (dates) and gives a pop-up if the date has passed or is within 2 weeks

Tags: excel, vba, popup

First timer here. I'm attempting to create a VBA pop-up that only returns the pop-up/warning if a date within a certain range, on a specific sheet is approaching (~2 weeks out). Is there a template or starting point for this?

I've gotten to the point of getting the pop-up when opening the workbook but don't know how to apply the calculation/formula necessary to look at the date range.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "TEST"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried searching some of these things on Google or Stackoverflow yet? How to read a range of data or a cell in a sheet? You haven't provided us with much information. Are you trying to read a range of cells or just one? You should also provide more information on what you have tried but doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I've done lots of google searching and haven't been able to piece the results together to get what I'm looking for. I'm trying to read a range of cells, in this instance "V:V", on sheet "Tracking_Log". The data in column V are dates. I'm looking to setup a pop-up message that indicates when one or more of the dates in column V is 2 weeks out from the date listed. I've tried changing and combining pieces of the below without success.

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 For Each r In Range("V:V").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
 r.ClearComments
If r.Value = Date - 14 Then '<< 2 weeks before
r.AddComment
 r.Comment.Text Text:="Review Expiration Dates."
 r.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
 r.Comment.Visible = True

 End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Review Expiration Dates. Client or Matter Rate Expiration Date Approaching/Passed"
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this should be a good start for you. I am no VBA expert. I actually know very little about it, but this did work for the few test cases I tried. I make no claim that this is the correct way to handle this.

```
Sub DateCheck()

    cmpDate = DateAdd("d", -14, Now())

    Range("A1").Select
    ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell.Value > cmpDate Then
            MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

You may need to change "A1" to the beginning of your range. This will start at A1 and progress row by row until it gets to a cell without a value. At each cell it compares the current date - 14days (cmpDate) with the date in the cell. If the active cell value is greater than cmpDate send a message with messagebox.